# NODE JS не верно принимаются данные POST запроса

Tags: php, node.js, post, curl

Код NODE JS:

```
var data = '';
sslserv.on('request', function(request, response) {
    if ((request.method=='POST' || request.method=='GET') && request.url.indexOf('socket')==-1){
        var data_arr = [];
        request.on('data', function(chunk) {
            data = chunk.toString();
            console.log(data);
        });
        request.on('end', function() {
            if (!data){
                response.write('It\'s Work!');
                response.end();
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Вот код отправки PHP:

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://127.0.0.1:8888");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

Когда на ноду через PHP_CURL приходит запрос длиною более 900 - 1000 символов, в консоль выходит не та информация, что была отправлена! 
В строке может появится лишний пробел или перенос строки...

Все бы ничего страшного, но я эту строку парсю через JSON.parse и в итоге вылетает ошибка! )) Грешил на функцию но после обратил внимание на то что данные запроса искажаются!

Почему?
Как исправить ?

Comment: Мне кажется, дело в том, что Вы пытаетесь выводить каждый чанк отдельным вызовом console.log, и, если собрать чанки в одну строку перед выводом, всё будет работать.

Comment: Может я вас не правильно понял, но речь идет об одном запросе! и о выводе в консоль одного тела запроса! Суть в том что если строка будет немного меньше - выдается правильно! Как добавлю к ней несколько символов - выводится не правильно... Может быть нода сама разделяет запрос на несколько кусков ???

Comment: За один запрос хэндлер request.on("data") может вызываться сколько угодно раз, и именно столько раз у Вас вызывается console.log, а не один. И нода тут непричем. Дело в размере запроса и настройках/возможностях сети.

Comment: Это похоже на реальность! Тогда ситуация проясняется)) значит нужно как то уловить и собрать в одно целое данные запроса.. с помощью данного хэндлера это возможно?

Comment: У вас какая-то каша. data не должна быть глобальной переменной. Она должна быть объявлена внутри обработчика запроса. И data_arr никак не используется

Comment: Да не обращайте внимания я это вижу )

Comment: Как собирать данные из запроса в строку я разобрался ) 
За это время еще научился использовать дополнение body-parser !
В принципе результат одинаковый (мои цели отрабатывает), только с body-parser писать нужно меньше кода!

Скажите что лучше все таки использовать body-parser или вырывать данные чанком и выводить JSON parse  ?   "Лучше" имеется ввиду объективно, касается нагрузки на машину, производительность и так далее.